# Wages maxed out at $25

Tags: tropico-4

I'm on my third play through. The first two times, I was able to raise wages to whatever I wanted.

On this play through though, I can't raise wages past $25. There's a red line half way down the slider showing the hard limit. This is going to be a problem because my high school education wage is approaching $20, and I don't want to discourage people from going to college.

Why can't I raise wages past $25, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't play this game, but after looking around some, there seems to be some sort of limit when you have the Cheapskate trait.  [This Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/tropico/comments/2hcfhf/how_do_i_change_the_minimum_wage/) mentions it:

> You can also get a red bar for maximum wage with the cheapskate leader attribute.

Looking at the Wiki for the trait [Cheapskate](http://tropico.wikia.com/wiki/Trait_(Tropico_3_and_4)#Cheapskate):

> -10 respect with the Communists, **maximum salary is set to $25/month**

I recommend you take a look at the traits you have for your presidente. If you have the Cheapskate one, then I think you have your answer.

Comment: I swear I looked! My google-Fu must be weak tonight. Yes, I chose a different character this run, and he does in fact have that trait. Thanks.